# nullpointerexception at getApplicationContext()

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to obtain the user's location, and this seems to be giving me trouble. 
When I call `distanceBetween()` to see test if it's working I get a NullPointerException at `getApplicationContext()`. Is there something I am not doing?

Here is the Stacktrace:

> java.lang.NullPointerException at
>   android.content.ContextWrapper.getApplicationContext(ContextWrapper.java:109)
>   at
>   com.ayy.zz.DistanceFinder.onCreate(DistanceFinder.java:38)
>   at
>   com.ayy.zz.DistanceFinder.distanceBetween(DistanceFinder.java:82)
>   at
>   com.ayy.zz.DistanceFinderTests.testSomething(DistanceFinderTests.java:14)
>   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) at
>   student.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:108) at
>   android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:191) at
>   android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:176) at
>   android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:554)
>   at
>   android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1701)

TestSomething is simply initializing a DistanceFinder and calling the distanceBetween method:

```
    public double distanceBetween()
    {
        onCreate();
        return dining1.distanceTo(dining2);
    }
```

Comment: Any time an exception gets thrown, post the stacktrace for the exception

Comment: Any particular reason you're extending application?

Comment: I thought it was required. I'm quite new to this, sorry. I'll remove that and try again.

Comment: Actually I need to extend Application to use getSystemService()

Comment: Please don't deface your post.

Comment: @DanielSetareh Please do not deface the post. If you need to remove information from it and can offer some proof of the concerns you have raised regarding this post, please raise a moderator flag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot simply call `onCreate` in order to get the context. It isn't clear what you are trying to do or when you are calling `distanceBetween` but it is obviously at a time before Android "creates" the Activity. ([What is 'Context' on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3572463/what-is-context-in-android))

Also, your `mContext` should not be static, and although it is permissible, this will give you access to the variable even when an instance is not created, also giving you an NPE.

When you are accessing `Context` you will need to be sure that Android has actually created / passed in a context for your object. In this case, an Activity must be "launched" before it will have context. This is true of `Service` and `BroadcastReceiver` classes as well.

Here are four solutions to getting `Context` -

1. Pass it into the method call, like this:

> ```
> public double distanceBetween(Context mContext)
> {
>     locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
>         .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
>     dining1 = new Location("");
>     dining1.setLatitude(37.226500);
>     dining1.setLongitude(-80.419179);
>     dining2 = new Location("");
>     dining2.setLatitude(37.229219);
>     dining2.setLongitude(-80.418310);
>     return dining1.distanceTo(dining2);
> }
> ```

2. Only call your method after the Activity is created by Android (not jsut by calling `onCreate()`
3. Create a `Service` and pass your requests to the Service and use its `Context`

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidServices/article.html

4. Cautiously consider using the `Application` class, which should be accessible any time your app is running.